# What is the best minimal http server?

Tags: webserver

If I want to serve some static content over http from Ubuntu, with an emphasis on security and efficiency (at low-moderate load), what's the best choice?

Answer (score 3):

We are using `micro-httpd` for this purpose.

It is very small and started by `inetd` for every single request, so it is only good for low-load environments, but it does what we need it do to. The only configuration options are the directory to be served and the port to listen on. For SSL/HTTPS support, `stunnel` would be used (a wrapper between unencrypted and ssl-encrypted connections).

Some more information from the man page:

> It implements all the basic
>      features of an HTTP server, including:
>
> - Security against ".." filename snooping.
> - The common MIME types.
> - Trailing-slash redirection.
> - index.html
> - Directory listings.

Answer (score 3):

**Apache** is very secure and extremely efficient at serving static content, especially at low-to-moderate load. It is also only an `apt-get` away, no additional configuration needed.

Is there anything which makes you to look for another web server?

Answer (score 0):

Very common are [Lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net) and [Nginx](http://nginx.org).
They are very alike and bear similar features and both support PHP if needed.
Lighttpd runs as a single process but with a single thread and non-blocking I/O,
where as Nginx works as one master process but delegates its work unto worker processes.